# Ngx paginator проблема с totalItems

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

В общем, поставил Ngx paginator

```
 <tr *ngFor="let user of users | paginate: paginator">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.username}}</td>
    </tr>

paginator = {
    itemsPerPage: number = 1;
    totalItems: number = 100;
    currentPage: number = 1;
}
```

Когда users.length = 5  отображает всех
как только длинна массива равняется с totalItems все начинает нормально работать 
PS Должно выводить по 1 на странице основываясь на параметре itemsPerPage

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmXZCRX1O93kIKvTQN2A?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

В общем я сделал форк и поправил одну строчку

было

```
if (!serverSideMode && collection instanceof Array) {
```

стало

```
 if (collection instanceof Array) {
```

в файле

```
src/ngx-pagination/paginate.pipe.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так интересно он [работает](http://plnkr.co/edit/JVQMPvV8z2brCIzdG3N4?p=preview). Вам надо что бы `users.length` совпадал с `itemsPerPage`.

сделать метод change который будет аяксом получать данные и изменять коллекцию.

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="change($event)"></pagination-controls>

 change(page) {
  //аякс и изменить коллекцию
 }
```

Comment: users.length совпадал с totalItems возможно вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: Если у вас users - это весь массив пользователей и вы его получаете 1 раз, то вам вообще  не надо писать totalItems, но если user это коллекция, которая изменяется при пагинации (то есть не вывод изменяется а весь массив users) то вам надо получать его ровно столько, сколько указано в itemsPerPage

Comment: да я его получаю столько сколько в itemsPerPage, выдается порциями, но если указать totalItems больше чем элементов в массиве, то на странице отображается неправильное количество элементов

Comment: В вашем примере `itemsPerPage = 1,` а `users.length = 5;`   `itemsPerPage != users.length` а должны равняться

Comment: по ссылке, которая, в [ответе](http://plnkr.co/edit/JVQMPvV8z2brCIzdG3N4?p=preview) в `src/app.ts` если поставить `{ itemsPerPage: 100, totalItems:1000, currentPage: p }`, то будет работать